# Symfony2 logout controller not found

Tags: php, symfony, logout

I have managed to get the login working in Symfony2, but I have trouble with /logout. I get an exception saying it can't find the controller for the route. However, I was under the impression that Symfony deals with the logout process, just like it deals with the login?

(part of) my security.yml file:

```
firewalls:
    login_firewall:
        pattern:    ^/login/
        anonymous:  ~
    secured_area:
        pattern:    ^/(dashboard|directories|login_check)/
        anonymous: ~
        form_login:
            login_path:  /login/
            check_path:  /login_check/
        logout:
            path:   /logout/
            target: /
```

My (relevant) routes:

```
_login:
    pattern: /login/
    defaults: { _controller: NanoBundle:Login:index } 

_login_check:
    pattern: /login_check/

_logout:
    pattern: /logout/
```

--edit: logout button code:

```
<a href="{{path('_logout')}}">Logout</a>
```

Comment: Show please listing of your logout button

Comment: Sure, my logout button is <a href="{{path('_logout')}}">Logout</a>

Comment: Please, post all your `routing.yml`. Looks like your `_logout` route is under some other regular expression

Comment: There is no extra line concerning logout (it's at the end of the file). So maybe i should edit the pattern-setting (although I don't think that would change much, considering login_check works fine)

Comment: Also, when I visit site.local/logout/ directly I get the error as well. Somehow it's not getting caught I think...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually fixed it with this security.yml section:

```
    secured_area:
        pattern:    .*
        security: true
        form_login:
            login_path:  /login/
            check_path:  /login_check/
        logout:
            path: /logout/
            invalidate_session: true
```

thanks to everyone for trying to help out on this :)

Answer (score 0):

fixed it with this security.yml section:

```
security:
    providers:
        fos_userbundle:
            id: fos_user.user_manager

encoders:
    FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: sha512

firewalls:
    main:
        pattern: ^/
        form_login:
            provider: fos_userbundle
            csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
        logout:       true
        anonymous:    true

access_control:
    - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/admin/*, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
     # URL of FOSUserBundle which need to be available to anonymous users
    - { path: ^/_wdt, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/_profiler, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }

role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_ADMIN
```

Try this may be helpful to you..:)

Comment: @QuintenVK : maybe it can helps someone else.